# sed replace (assistance required)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I have one file at `/var/www/html/daloradius/library/daloradius.conf.php`

which have the below-mentioned lines :

```
$configValues['CONFIG_DB_PORT'] = '3306'
$configValues['CONFIG_DB_USER'] = 'root'
```

I want to replace '3306' ---> '5432' and  'root' --> 'postgres'
using a shell script so please assist me how to using sed command.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suggest opening the file in your favourite editor and just change the values.

Comment: No @TedLyngmo as I need to use this command in a shell script.

Comment: Why is that? That means that something is overwriting your edits constantly.

Comment: What is the question? This is trivial if you spend 5 minutes reading the documentation for sed. With what do you need assistance?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sir, this is for one-time configuration only

Comment: For a one-time configuration - just **edit** the file. Why mess with a script to do it?

Comment: Sorry for this but I don't know how to handle whitespace in sed command.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files to get started with using sed

Comment: Then your question title should be "How to handle whitespace in sed command" and you should include the command that you tried in the question itself. We can't read your mind, you need to tell where you're stuck.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Sorry Sir my mistake

Comment: You still haven't explained why you prefer doing it with `sed` rather than with an editor. This is why editors exist.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am writing a shell script for installing Apache, Postgresql, Freeradius, PHP and this daloradius website on my client's system, so I need to make changes in 2-3 config files which I had done manually.

Comment: @NaveenPurohit Ok, that makes sense. I'll provide something to work on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the criteria for making the change. For example do you want to change the number 3306 to 5432, or whatever number appears first in the file to 5432, or the number between single quotes at the end of a line that starts with `$configValues['CONFIG_DB_PORT'] =` or do you want to change 3306 to whatever value is stored in an environment variable named `CONFIG_DB_PORT` or do you want to change all numbers on lines that look like `$configValues['<string>'] = '<number>'` to the value of whatever variable is named by `<string>` or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton In this case I think it's just a matter of brute force editing a `php` configuration upon installation. `$configValues['CONFIG_DB_PORT']` is "hardcoded".

Answer (score 0):

If you can't prepare the config file prior to installation and just unpack your version over the standard config, you could make your `bash` script something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

dalconf="/var/www/html/daloradius/library/daloradius.conf.php"

cleanup() {
    rm -f "$tmpfile"
}

trap cleanup EXIT
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

# '3306' --> '5432' and 'root' --> 'postgres'

sed -E -e "s/'3306'/'5432'/" -e "s/'root'/'postgres'/" "$dalconf" > "$tmpfile"
mv "$tmpfile" "$dalconf"
```

Note: Any match on `'3306'` or `'root'` will match so increase the matching strings as much as you'd like to feel comfortable.